Know permissions active for a user or service
I am working with AWS STS, an account has to connect to another account and retrieve some s3 files.
I am facing lots of permission issues. Since permissions can be given in a multiple different levels I wonder if there is any kind of way to visualize what permissions are being applied for a given user or service so I can find where it is given/denied access to it.
Are there any way to visualize them in the console?

Not really, the closest may be the IAM Policy Simulator (https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) but that comes with a range of limitations such as not supporting cross-account use cases (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). From my experience this is frequently an iterative process, although error messages have been getting a lot more helpful recently.

There's 3 levels you have to think about: 1. the identity based policy on your user / role doing the s3 operation needs to allow the operation.  2. the resource based policy (in your case bucket policy) needs to allow the user or the user's account; 3) the SCPs in both organizations must allow the operation.  I don't recommend the policy simulator; it's more confusing than it is illuminating.

Are you referring/trying to assume a role in another account to get s3 files in the another account? Why not just use bucket policy in another account. There is no  need to assume a role at all.
